# Link Google Play Real-Time Developer Notifications in AWS Cloud?Or Is there any way of getting purchase notifs in Instances not in Google Cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-play

Is there any way of using Google Play Real-Time Developer Notifications but in an AWS Cloud? Like if google can notify my cloud by calling a webhook or my URL that the purchase has been made?

In the docs https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/rtdn-reference?authuser=2

Google mentioned to get purchase notifications using Google cloud **Pub/sub**. but what about if we are not using google Cloud? What is the procedure there? Or Is there any way of getting purchase notifications in Instance not in Google Cloud?